# Regex for time input

Tags: javascript, regex

I can have the following kinds of value I receive from the input:

1w 1d 1h 1m

or

1н 1д 1ч 1м

Where the week (w) and day (d) options are optional and the rest is obligatory. I came up with the following regex:

/^(([0-9][w,н])\s([0-9][d,д]))\s?([0-24][h,ч])\s([0-60][m,м])$/

But it's not working.

I think I messed up the optional part and I'm not quite sure about the capturing groups as well, so any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show us what your input and results were using your regexp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works: `(?:\d[wн]\s)?(?:\d[dд]\s)?(:?\d{1,2}[hч])\s(:?\d{1,2}[mм])`

See: https://regex101.com/r/X4ObPD/2

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does! I will accept this answer in 4 mins :)

Comment: Be aware that in this regex week and day are both optional independently. So you can left out only the day or only the week or both.

Comment: Please see: https://regex101.com/r/X4ObPD/2, I covered all cases.

Comment: @ChristianBaumann btw, is it also possible to make minutes & hours optional?
In case I want to enter only minutes or hours

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
/^(?:\d+[wн]\s+\d+[dд]\s+)?\d+[чh]\s+\d+[мm]$/
```

Comment: This only captures one digit for hour and minutes, whereas you can see from Mike's try, that it should capture two digits.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the regex class operator `[..]` wrong. I see your intention to set the allowed range, but this is not how it works. You can only set the allowed character set here. So `[0-9]` simply means, all characters 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 are allowed. How many of them is specified afterwards, e.g. `[0-9]+` means one or more. In your case I'd say "one or two" is what you want for minutes and hours like `[0-9]{1,2}`.

The following regex works as expected:

```
^(([0-9]+)[wн]\s([0-9]+)[dд]\s)?(([0-9]{1,2})[hч]\s)(([0-9]{1,2})[mм])$
```

Please note that you have to do the value validation (so hours and minutes are in the right range) afterwards programmatically.